# Reinforcement learning in real world without OpenAI Gym

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have been searching for reinforcement learning libraries or examples that aren't using a simulated environment like OpenAI Gym. I havn't been successful at all until yet and I would really appreciate if someone knows some examples/libraries.
If someone is familiar with Optunas ask-and-tell procedure, thats would be exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Maybe not quite what you are looking for, but may be interesting: https://mushroomrl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you very much, I will have a look